# What mean by char(40)?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table which has a data structure as follows,

```
create table data(
....
name char(40) NULL,

...
)
```

But I could insert names which has characters more than 40 in to name field. Can someone explain what is the actual meaning of char(40)?

Comment: This is how "wide" your column is... e.g. 40 characters wide (max)

Comment: Does this mean any kind of data loss, such as data part cut?

Comment: This is covered in the second para of the manual page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html and you really should familiarise yourself with the manual

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot insert a string of more than 40 characters in a column defined with the type CHAR(40).

If you run MySQL in strict mode, you will get an error if you try to insert a longer string.

```
mysql> create table mytable ( c char(40) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into mytable (c) values ('Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.');
ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'c' at row 1
```

If you run MySQL in non-strict mode, the insert will succeed, but only the first 40 characters of your string is stored in the column. The characters beyond 40 are lost, and you get no error.

```
mysql> set sql_mode='';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into mytable (c) values ('Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'c' at row 1 |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select c from mytable;
+------------------------------------------+
| c                                        |
+------------------------------------------+
| Now is the time for all good men to come |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I recommend operating MySQL in strict mode (strict mode is the default since MySQL 5.7). I would prefer to get an error instead of losing data.